# Proof of a limit that results in minus infinity

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

Using the $M-\delta$ definition of a limit, proof that

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2})} = - \infty
$$

I've tried to write the proof, but I got stuck in determining what $\delta$ should be picked.  Here's my thought process:

Given $M<0$ 
Choose $\delta =$ 
Suppose $0<x<\delta$ 
We see that:
$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x-1}{x^2}$$

I'm having a trouble in determining the boundaries for $x-1$ and $x^2$. I know that both of those terms should be less than something, but I'm having trouble finding those boundaries.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried? Usually on this site we expect people asking questions to post their progress or attempts. This site isn't for asking questions and expecting complete answers.

Comment: Thanks for the inside! It's my first time using this site and I don't know what to include in the question.

Comment: The reasoning for this kind of limit should go like this: No matter how large negative $M$ is, we can force $f(x)$ below $M$ by putting $x$ in the interval $(0, \delta)$. Then we show that for all $x$ in that interval, $f(x) < M$. ¶ In many cases, like this one, $f(x)$ is monotonic in some nice interval like $(0, 1)$, so as long as $f(\delta) < M$, we're done.

Comment: P.S. `$\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$` yields the nicer looking $\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  It's also my first time using LaTex so I'm still a bit confused.